Is there a "minimal free resolution" for non-finitely generated modules?
Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a commutative local ring and $M$ be an $R$-module such that $\mathfrak m^n M=0$ for some $n>0$. Then, does there exist a projective (necessarily free by Kaplansky's theorem) $R$-module $F$ and an $R$-linear surjection $F\xrightarrow{f} M \to 0$ such that $\ker(f) \subseteq \mathfrak m F$ ?
I know this is true when $R$ is moreover Noetherian and $M$ is finitely generated ...

Pick a set of elements in $M$ which forms a basis for the $R/\mathfrak{m}$ vector space $M/\mathfrak{m}M$. Easy to check that they generate $M$ and gives you a minimal free resolution.
